# Your code threw a "string indices must be integers, not str" error

Tags: python-2.7

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

student=[lloyd,alice,tyler]

def get_avg(stu_lst):
    return sum(stu_lst)/float(len(stu_lst))

def weight_average(lst):
    return get_avg(lst["homework"])*0.1+get_avg(lst["quizzes"])*0.3+get_avg(lst["tests"])*0.6

def get_average(students):
    for student in students:
       print weight_average(student)

get_average(student)
```

Comment: I'm wondering if this a question or if someone pasted their code to SO by mistake....!

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work fine. I think you have an indentation problem. Make sure the code is properly indented and run it again

Answer (score 0):

You have `identation` problem right here:

[image]

Fix that and it will work.